# ¿Cómo evitar la carga de un mp3 cuando se esté reproduciendo otro en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo varias canciones en la página. Me pregunto ¿cómo evito la carga automática de las canciones que no estén sonando?

Por ejemplo con:

```
<audio id="audio1">
      <source src="mp3/ideas/amanece.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio id="audio2">
      <source src="mp3/ideas/otro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Hasta ahora, logré poner en pausa a las anteriores, pero me cargo la reproducción de todas las canciones. Se me ocurrió poner `audio1.src="";` cuando se de play en audio2, pero no lo puedo usar de esa forma.

```
// en la función siguiente hago que cuando una canción se reproduzca y se pulse en otra canción
// se deje de reproducir la anterior (para limitar la reproducción a la vez de una sola canción)

var audios;

document.addEventListener('play', function(e)
{

    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');


    for(var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len;i++)
    {
        if(audios[i] != e.target)
        {
            audios[i].pause();
            //audios[i].src = "";  //por ejemplo aquí no lo puedo usar        
        }
    }           

}, true);
```

Estoy usando el código del compañero Error404 pero la llamada a la función la hago desde el icono "play" de cada canción no desde las etiquetas audio...

```
function play(id)
{
       var audio = document.getElementById(id);

       if (id == "audio1")
       {

           document.getElementById("audio1").src = "mp3/ideas/amanece.mp3";
           document.getElementById("audio2").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio3").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio4").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio5").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio6").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio7").src = "";

       }
       if (id == "audio2")
       {
           document.getElementById("audio1").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio2").src = "mp3/ideas/escupitajo.mp3";
           document.getElementById("audio3").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio4").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio5").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio6").src = "";
           document.getElementById("audio7").src = "";

       }
       else
       {
          // document.getElementById("audio1").src = "";
       }
}

<img id="idplay1"  class="play"  data-audio="1" data-img="1" src="images/play.png"  onclick="play('audio1')">
```

y funciona, evito la carga de la cancion que estaba sonando (cuando hago click en ella otra vez empieza a reproducir desde 0) pero no puedo pausar la reproducción de una canción.

Answer (score 1):

El tag [`audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/audio) de `HTML5` posee el atributo llamado [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/audio#Atributos), el cual si es establecido como `none`, evitara que el archivo sea descargado automáticamente. Solo será descargado cuando el usuario haga `click` sobre el mismo.

```html
<audio  preload="none" controls>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero no puedes usar un ID en más de un elemento, puesto que como su propio nombre indica, son identificadores y representan a un solo elemento. En su defecto deberías usar una clase.

```
<audio class="audio" id="audio1" onclick="play("audio1")>
      <source src="mp3/ideas/amanece.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>

<audio class="audio" id="audio2" onclick="play("audio2")>
      <source src="mp3/ideas/amanece.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

Una vez hecho esto, podemos crear una función para cuando le demos click a cada uno de los audios pasándole como parámetro la id del mismo (el que clickemos):

```
function play(id){
       var audio = document.getElementById(id);

       if (id == "audio1"){
           document.getElementById("audio2").src = "";
       }else{
           document.getElementById("audio1").src = "";
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guarda el src en una propiedad personalizada, para poder recuperarla después de limpiar el src.
Como al limpiar el src, su valor pasa a ser la url actual (no se porqué), para saber si un audio tiene un src "vacío", compáralo con "" por si es "nuevo" y con location.href por si ha sido "limpiado".
Algo parecido a esto: (si pulsas en el que suena, lo pausa)

```js
function play(id){
 var elementosAudio=document.getElementsByTagName("AUDIO");
 for (let i=0; i<elementosAudio.length; i++)
  if (elementosAudio[i].id!=id) elementosAudio[i].src = "";
  else if (elementosAudio[i].paused) {
   if (elementosAudio[i].src=="" || elementosAudio[i].src==location.href)
    elementosAudio[i].src=elementosAudio[i].getAttribute('data-src');
   elementosAudio[i].play();
  }
  else elementosAudio[i].pause();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play('audio1')">Audio 1</button>
<button onclick="play('audio2')">Audio 2</button>
<AUDIO id="audio1" data-src="http://k002.kiwi6.com/hotlink/qp7vm37342/Afrim_rique.mp3"></AUDIO>
<AUDIO id="audio2" data-src="http://k007.kiwi6.com/hotlink/5ntn5xh2vc/Au-dessus_des_nuages.mp3"></AUDIO>
```

Bonus track:
Si no te gusta que al asignar "" a src salga un aviso en consola, puedes reemplazar el objeto por otro nuevo, copiándole los atributos.
Algo parecido a esto:

```js
function play(id){
 var elementosAudio=document.getElementsByTagName("AUDIO");
 for (let i=0; i<elementosAudio.length; i++)
  if (elementosAudio[i].id!=id && elementosAudio[i].src!="") {
   let audio=document.createElement("AUDIO");
   audio.id=elementosAudio[i].id;
   audio.setAttribute('data-src',elementosAudio[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
   elementosAudio[i].parentNode.replaceChild(audio,elementosAudio[i]);
  }
  else if (elementosAudio[i].id==id)
   if (elementosAudio[i].paused) {
    if (elementosAudio[i].src=="")
     elementosAudio[i].src=elementosAudio[i].getAttribute('data-src');
    elementosAudio[i].play();
   }
   else elementosAudio[i].pause();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="play('audio1')">Audio 1</button>
<button onclick="play('audio2')">Audio 2</button>
<AUDIO id="audio1" data-src="http://k002.kiwi6.com/hotlink/qp7vm37342/Afrim_rique.mp3"></AUDIO>
<AUDIO id="audio2" data-src="http://k007.kiwi6.com/hotlink/5ntn5xh2vc/Au-dessus_des_nuages.mp3"></AUDIO>
```